# Jquery Select a tr by an hidden input field value inside a td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a beginner with jQuery language and I've got a question.

I've got a Table in my website like this:

```
<table id="filter-table" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Typology</th>
      <th>Select</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>IYCE8</td>
      <td>NAME</td>
      <td>
        <input class='typology' type='hidden' value='1'>TYPE1
        <input class='typology' type='hidden' value='2'>TYPE2
        <input class='typology' type='hidden' value='3'>TYPE3
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>IYCE9</td>
      <td>NAME2</td>
      <td>
        <input class='typology' type='hidden' value='1'>TYPE1
        <input class='typology' type='hidden' value='2'>TYPE2
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

as you can see rows have an hidden input associated to a typology (type1=>1).

with a dropdown selector i choose a value:

```
<select id="filter" name="filter">
  <option value="">SELECT ONE</option>
  <option value="1">TYPE1</option>
  <option value="2">TYPE2</option>
  <option value="3">TYPE3</option>
</select>
```

With the event OnChange in a filter i want to select all the rows in the table that have the input field value = to the one selected in the dropdown

How i can do this with Jquery?
Thanks in advance for all the help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could combine an [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and the [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/8mw79b95/)

```
$('#filter').on('change', function () {
  var $tr = $('#filter-table tr:has(.typology[value="' + this.value + '"])');
});
```

In the snippet above, `$tr` is a jQuery object that contains all the desendant `tr` elements that contain an element with a class of `.typology` and a value attribute corresponding to the selected value.

Comment: OMG you even prepared a fiddle thank you man this works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You can first get the value needed and then use it for whatever you need to find:

```
$('#filter').on('change', function () {
  var selected_val = this.value;
  var els_needed = $('#filter-table').children().find('input.typology[value="'+selected_val+'"]');
});
```