# Search and filter through html table input textbox using input textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a table which contains **itemcode** field.I want to filter item code. I have bind the item code with input textbox inside html table because item code is editable. 
I tried with given below code:

```js
function loadiTems() {
  var table = $('#tblDetItems').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "keys": true,
    "retrieve": true,
    "bLengthChange": false,
    "ordering": false,
    "scrollY": 300,
    "scrollX": false
  });

  $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_rptItems_txt_ItemCode_tbl').val('');
  $('#ContentPlaceHolder1_rptItems_txtslno_tbl').bind('keyup', function (e) {
    table.columns(1).search("^" + this.value, true, true, true).draw();
  });
}
```

### the above code worked with normal columns. Please help me to find a solution

```html
<table cellspacing="10" border="1" width="1200px">
  <tr style="border-style: none;">
    <td style="border-style: none;">
      <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptItems">
        <HeaderTemplate>
          <table id="tblDetItems" border="1" style="font-size: 9pt; border-color: #A9A9A9; position: relative;" class="display" cellspacing="0">
            <thead style="background: #808080; color: White; font-weight: bold; border-color: White;">
              <tr>
                <th style="width: 10px;">
                  SlNo.
                </th>
                <th style="width: 200px;">
                  Item Code
                </th>
                <th style="width: 300px;">
                  Description
                </th>
                <th style="width: 80px;">
                  Group
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  Supplier
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  Material
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  Scode1
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  Labour1
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  Scode2
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  Labour2
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  Scode3
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  Labour3
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  Scode4
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  Labour4
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  Scode5
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  Labour5
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  A Scode
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  Assembly
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  Replace Cost
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  Total
                </th>
              </tr>
              <tr style="background-color: Silver; height: 45px;">
                <th style="width: 10px;">
                  <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 60px;" id="txtslno_tbl" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 200px;">
                  <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 200px;" id="txt_ItemCode_tbl" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 300px;">
                  <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 300px;" id="txtDesc_tbl" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 80px;">
                  <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 80px;" id="txtGroup_tbl" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_Supplier_tbl" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_Material_tbl" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_SCode1_tbl" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_Labour1_tbl" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_SCode2_tbl" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_Labour2_tbl" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_SCode3_tbl" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_Labour3_tbl" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_SCode4_tbl" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_Labour4_tbl" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_SCode1_tb5" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_Labour1_tb5" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_A_SCode_tbl" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_Assembly_tbl" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_ReplaceCost_tbl" />
                </th>
                <th style="width: 100px;">
                  <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 100px;" id="txt_Total_tbl" />
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </HeaderTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
            <tr id="tr_id">
              <td id="slno" style="width: 10px; text-align: right; height: 13px;">
                <%# Eval("sl_no")%>
                  </td>
              <td style="width: 200px; height: 13px;">
                <%# Eval("item_cd")%>
                  </td>
              <td style="width: 300px; height: 13px;">
                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 290px; text-align: left; height: 13px;"
                       class="fooClass" id="txt_item_desc" value='<%# Eval("item_desc")%>' />
              </td>
              <td style="width: 80px; height: 13px;">
                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 70px; text-align: left; height: 13px;"
                       id="txt_gp_cd" value='<%# Eval("gp_cd")%>' />
              </td>
              <td style="width: 100px; height: 13px;">
                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: left; height: 13px;"
                       id="txt_sup_scode" value='<%# Eval("sup_scode")%>' />
              </td>
              <td style="width: 100px; text-align: right; height: 13px;">
                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: right; height: 13px;"
                       maxlength="10" id="txt_material" value='<%# Eval("mtrl_cost")%>' onkeydown='return isNumberKey(event)' />
              </td>
              <td style="width: 100px; height: 13px;">
                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: left; height: 13px;"
                       id="txt_sup_scode1" value='<%# Eval("lbr1_scode")%>' />
              </td>
              <td style="width: 100px; text-align: right; height: 13px;">
                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: right; height: 13px;"
                       maxlength="10" id="txt_labour1" value='<%# Eval("lbr1_cost")%>' onkeydown='return isNumberKey(event)' />
              </td>
              <td style="width: 100px; height: 13px;">
                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: left; height: 13px;"
                       id="txt_sup_scode2" value='<%# Eval("lbr2_scode")%>' />
              </td>
              <td style="width: 100px; text-align: right; height: 13px;">
                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: right; height: 13px;"
                       maxlength="10" id="txt_labour2" value='<%# Eval("lbr2_cost")%>' onkeydown='return isNumberKey(event)' />
              </td>
              <td style="width: 100px; height: 13px;">
                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: left; height: 13px;"
                       id="txt_sup_scode3" value='<%# Eval("lbr3_scode")%>' />
              </td>
              <td style="width: 100px; text-align: right; height: 13px;">
                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: right; height: 13px;"
                       maxlength="10" id="txt_labour3" value='<%# Eval("lbr3_cost")%>' onkeydown='return isNumberKey(event)' />
              </td>
              <td style="width: 100px; height: 13px;">
                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: left; height: 13px;"
                       id="txt_sup_scode4" value='<%# Eval("lbr4_scode")%>' />
              </td>
              <td style="width: 100px; text-align: right; height: 13px;">
                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: right; height: 13px;"
                       maxlength="10" id="txt_labour4" value='<%# Eval("lbr4_cost")%>' onkeydown='return isNumberKey(event)' />
              </td>
              <td style="width: 100px; height: 13px;">
                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: left; height: 13px;"
                       id="txt_sup_scode5" value='<%# Eval("lbr5_scode")%>' />
              </td>
              <td style="width: 100px; text-align: right; height: 13px;">
                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: right; height: 13px;"
                       maxlength="10" id="txt_labour5" value='<%# Eval("lbr5_cost")%>' onkeydown='return isNumberKey(event)' />
              </td>
              <td style="width: 100px; height: 13px;">
                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: left; height: 13px;"
                       id="txt_a_s_scode" value='<%# Eval("assmbly_scode")%>' />
              </td>
              <td style="width: 100px; text-align: right; height: 13px;">
                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: right; height: 13px;"
                       maxlength="10" id="txt_assembly" value='<%# Eval("assmbly_chrge")%>' onkeydown='return isNumberKey(event)' />
              </td>
              <td style="width: 100px; text-align: right; height: 13px;">
                <input type="text" runat="server" style="width: 90px; text-align: right; height: 13px;"
                       maxlength="10" id="txt_replace_cost" value='<%# Eval("replace_cost")%>' onkeydown='return isNumberKey(event)' />
              </td>
              <td style="width: 100px; text-align: right; height: 13px;">
                <%# Eval("purc_rate")%>
                  </td>
            </tr>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <FooterTemplate>
            </tbody> </table>
        </FooterTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How search into options of select tag html without plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27713621/how-search-into-options-of-select-tag-html-without-plugin)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery Select a tr by an hidden input field value inside a td](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398277/jquery-select-a-tr-by-an-hidden-input-field-value-inside-a-td)